# The name 'currentUserId' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to insert data into SQL Server from ASP.NET C# but getting the error code:

> The name 'currentUserId' does not exist in the current context.

I am getting this error on the protected bankinfo. How do I declare the `currentuserid` so that it can be accessible throughout all the page. When I run my page I get the above error message

```
public bool InsertRegistration()
{
    // Determine the currently logged on user's UserId

    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid currentUserId = (Guid) currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

    //Start of Upload 1
    string filename1 = Path.GetFileName(AdmissionUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
    string contentType1 = AdmissionUpload.PostedFile.ContentType;
    using (Stream fs1 = AdmissionUpload.PostedFile.InputStream)
    {
        using (BinaryReader br1 = new BinaryReader(fs1))
        {
            byte[] bytes1 = br1.ReadBytes((Int32) fs1.Length);


            string filename2 = Path.GetFileName(StudentIDUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
            string contentType2 = StudentIDUpload.PostedFile.ContentType;
            using (Stream fs2 = StudentIDUpload.PostedFile.InputStream)
            {
                using (BinaryReader br2 = new BinaryReader(fs2))
                {
                    byte[] bytes2 = br2.ReadBytes((Int32) fs2.Length);


                    string filename3 = Path.GetFileName(TranscriptUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
                    string contentType3 = TranscriptUpload.PostedFile.ContentType;
                    using (Stream fs3 = TranscriptUpload.PostedFile.InputStream)
                    {
                        using (BinaryReader br3 = new BinaryReader(fs3))
                        {
                            byte[] bytes3 = br3.ReadBytes((Int32) fs3.Length);


                            string filename4 = Path.GetFileName(PassportUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
                            string contentType4 = PassportUpload.PostedFile.ContentType;
                            using (Stream fs4 = PassportUpload.PostedFile.InputStream)
                            {
                                using (BinaryReader br4 = new BinaryReader(fs4))
                                {
                                    byte[] bytes4 = br4.ReadBytes((Int32) fs4.Length);

                                    //SqlDateTime sqldatenull;
                                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
                                        "INSERT INTO DocInfoNationalCandidates2020edited(AdmissionLetter, AdmissionLetterFileName, AdmissionImageType, StudentID, StudentIDFileName, StudentImageType, Transcript, TranscriptFileName, TranscriptImageType, Passport,  PassportFileName, PassportImageType,  UserId) OUTPUT INSERTED.ApplicationNo VALUES (@AdmissionLetter, @AdmissionLetterFileName, @AdmissionImageType, @StudentID, @StudentIDFileName, @StudentImageType,  @Transcript, @TranscriptFileName, @TranscriptImageType, @Passport,  @PassportFileName, @PassportImageType, @UserId)",
                                        con);
                                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdmissionLetter", bytes1).Value =
                                        System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary.Null;
                                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdmissionLetterFileName", filename1);
                                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdmissionImageType", contentType1);

                                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", bytes2).Value =
                                        System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary.Null;
                                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentIDFileName", filename2);
                                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentImageType", contentType2);

                                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transcript", bytes3).Value =
                                        System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary.Null;
                                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TranscriptFileName", filename3);
                                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TranscriptImageType", contentType2);

                                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passport", bytes4).Value =
                                        System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary.Null;
                                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassportFileName", filename4);
                                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassportImageType", contentType4);

                                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);

                                    con.Open();

                                    // open connection here, just before executing
                                    // return the true/false for whether a row was inserted

                                    int rows = com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                    if (rows > 0)
                                    {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


protected void btnbankinfosub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com =
        new SqlCommand(
            "INSERT INTO BankInfoNationalCandidates2020(Bank, AccountNo, SortCode, UserId) VALUES (@Bank, @AccountNo, @SortCode, @UserId )",con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bank", ddlbankname.SelectedItem.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNo", txtaccno.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortCode", txtsortcode.Text);


    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);
 

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    lblbankinfo.Visible = true;
    lblbankinfo.Text = "Saved successfully!";
    lblbankinfo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you're trying to use currentUserId in btnbankinfosub_Click but you only declare it in InsertRegistration.

The simple fix is to just copy these lines to the top of btnbankinfosub_Click:

```
// Determine the currently logged on user's UserId
MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
Guid currentUserId = (Guid) currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

However you could also refactor these out into a function or property, e.g.

```
private Guid CurrentUserId {
    get {
        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        return (Guid) currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
    }
}
```

and then all of your code on the page can use `CurrentUserId`.

(That said, this code will be run every time you read the property; if this were relatively expensive to compute you'd want to ensure it was computed once then cached for the lifetime of this controller, but I think in this case fetching data from Membership is quick so that's not worth worrying about here.)

Comment: Thank you so much @Rup. The first option worked!!!!